# Telegram sendInvoice method is failing

Tags: telegram

Hello stack overflow so when I am testing a stripe transaction with testing credit cards. I get a "bot precheckout timeout" error and cannot succeed with the tested transaction. After the stripe payment I would like to see a success method. Here is my source code.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const invoiceDescription = require('./constants');

const { TOKEN, SERVER_URL, BOTTOKEN } = process.env;
const TELEGRAM_API = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}`;
const URI = `/webhook/${TOKEN}`;
const WEBHOOK_URL = SERVER_URL + URI;

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const init = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${TELEGRAM_API}/setWebhook?url=${WEBHOOK_URL}`);
  console.log(res.data);
};

app.post(URI, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
  let text = "", chatId = "", userObjectForTable = {}; 
  if(req.body.message?.chat?.id && req.body.message?.text){
        chatId = req.body.message.chat.id;
        text = req.body.message.text;
        await axios.post(`${TELEGRAM_API}/sendMessage`, {
            chat_id: chatId,
            text: text,
        });
    }
  if (text === "/pay") {
    const message = await axios.post(`${TELEGRAM_API}/sendInvoice`, {
      chat_id: chatId,
      title: `FinnessinPips`,
      description: invoiceDescription,
      payload: "Invoice for payment",
      provider_token: BOTTOKEN,
      currency: "USD",
      prices: [{ label: "tax", amount: 4000 }],
    });
    userObjectForTable = {
        date: new Date(message.data.result.date),
        username: message.data.result.from.username
    }
  }
  if(req.body.pre_checkout_query?.id){
    //save to sqlite
    console.log("saving to sqlite", req.body)
    await axios.post(`${TELEGRAM_API}/sendMessage`, {
        chat_id: req.body.pre_checkout_query?.from.id,
        text: "Successfully Payed private url is",
    });
}
  return res.send();
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5050, async () => {
  console.log(" app running on port", process.env.PORT || 5050);
  await init();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at "7. Pre-Checkout" section in the Payment API here: https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments#7-pre-checkout

More specifically :

> Your bot must reply using answerPrecheckoutQuery within 10 seconds after receiving this update or the transaction is canceled.